# Using this keyword to select children

Tags: jquery, this, children

What's the syntax for the $this keyword when selecting its child element/s?

For example when selecting images of the first cell in a table:  `$("this td:eq(0) img")`, or,  `$($this "td:eq(0) img")`, etc, like should there be quotes, a dollar sign etc, and if so, where?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just the [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function?

```
$(this).find('td:eq(0) img');
```

Comment: Can you use css() with find() though, for example $this.find('td:eq(0) img').css("width", "200px")?

Comment: Of course. `find()` returns a jQuery object, the same as `$()`.

Comment: sorry late here, but find(elementname).hover(function(){code}) worked, thanks.